# How could I use boolean index to retrieve columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

df1:DataFrame

```
    0   1   2   3   4
a   0   1   2   3   4
b   5   6   7   8   9
c  10  11  12  13  14
d  15  16  17  18  19
```

I can retrieve rows using the following way.

```
df1[(df1>10).any(1)]

In [58]: df1[(df1>10).any(1)]
Out[58]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
c  10  11  12  13  14
d  15  16  17  18  19
```

But when I want to retrieve columns, in this way: df[(df1>10).any(0)].

It throws exception.

```
   1699 
   1700         result = result.astype(bool)._values

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

How can I realise it?

Comment: What do you want? Any column with a value greater than 10 (which is all your columns in this example)?

Comment: Yes, this is a quiz not a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loc` and specify the relevant column constraints.

```
>>> df1.loc[:, df1.gt(10).any(axis=0)]
    0   1   2   3   4
a   0   1   2   3   4
b   5   6   7   8   9
c  10  11  12  13  14
d  15  16  17  18  19
```